Does Euro Truck Simulator 2 have multiplayer?
When I go to the Steam ETS2 page, it has Co-op Online tag. However, when I google about it, all I find is about a mod to play it online. I know many years ago it wasn't possible to play it multiplayer.
Is it now included to play it co-op directly from Steam without having to host a server and/or adding a multiplayer mod?

Yes, Euro Truck Simulator 2 now has official multiplayer support. Read more at https://www.pcgamesn.com/euro-truck-simulator-2/141-convoy-multiplayer

The question mentions not needing to add a multiplayer mod, but I'm documenting this here for completeness' sake.
Additional to the official Convoy feature that is available in Euro Truck Simulator 2 (and American Truck Simulator), there is also TruckersMP, an unofficial multiplayer mod and hosted server with support for up to 4300 players.
This is probably the mod that is referred to when you Google "ets2 multiplayer". This predated the official multiplayer support by about 7 years, and at the time was the main method used to play ETS2 and ATS with multiple players. Because it's an unofficial mod, it's prone to breaking when a game update is released (though usually, it's easy to temporarily downgrade the game if necessary). The Convoy system doesn't suffer the same problem, thanks to it being a first-party feature.

Very complete answer, thank you very much :)
